# H3 geo addressing scheme based on aperture 7 hierarchy

Tags: hierarchy, geo, uber-api, addressing, h3

using h3geo grid system, i was curious if it would be possible to create an addressing scheme based on the aperture 7 hierachy?. eg 121.0.1.2.3.4.5.6 etc.

The first number is the base cell and the subsequent numbers are one of the seven hexagons in the resolution below (higher resolution).  we would assume the center hexagon is 0 and follow the Central Place Indexing aperture 7 numbering pattern
see slide 25 [http://webpages.sou.edu/~sahrk/sqspc/pubs/autocarto14.pdf](http://webpages.sou.edu/%7Esahrk/sqspc/pubs/autocarto14.pdf)

[image: aperture 7 child hexagons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s exactly how the H3 index works. An H3 index is a 64-bit integer, and in those bits we encode some metadata, the base cell, and the 0-6 child digits of the children at each resolution (or 7 for digits beyond the encoded resolution).

See [this notebook](https://observablehq.com/@nrabinowitz/h3-index-bit-layout) for more details on the bit layout of the index.